# Uncaught ReferenceError: Rails is not defined in Rails 7 with Webpack

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, webpack, yarn-v2

im having a bug in my Rails config and dont know what to do anymore. It is not disturbing any of my code, but i want to know why this problem occurs and if i may have problems with it in the near future. I am using Rails 7 with webpack. Error occured while working with actioncable and channels, using javascript inside with:

```
document.addEventListener('turbolinks:load', () => {})
```

**Error Message: Uncaught ReferenceError: Rails is not defined in my browser console.**

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Rails is not defined
    js application.js:17
    Webpack 3
```

**Application.js**

```
require("@rails/ujs").start()
require("turbolinks").start()
require("@rails/activestorage").start()
require("channels")
require("jquery")
import '../stylesheets/application.scss'
//import '../src/message.js'




Rails.start()
Turbolinks.start()
ActiveStorage.start()
```

**environment.js in config/webpack**

```
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')

const webpack = require('webpack')
environment.plugins.prepend('Provide',
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        $: 'jquery/src/jquery',
        jQuery: 'jquery/src/jquery'
    })
)


module.exports = environment
```

**Additional Gems**

```
gem 'tether-rails'
gem 'jquery-rails'
```

**yarn.lock**

```
"@rails/ujs@^7.0.1":
  version "7.0.1"
```

That are all files i know about them having rails ujs, but i am not sure what my problem is exactily. Did i do something wrong in regard of my project configuration? I am inexpierienced in setting up rails and kinda lost on this one.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to call

```
Rails.start()
Turbolinks.start()
ActiveStorage.start()
```

You can remove those 3 lines, I guess you got confused with other examples like this one https://guides.rubyonrails.org/webpacker.html#using-webpacker-for-javascript where the library first got imported and then started. In your example `require("@rails/ujs").start()` you are doing both things at the same time.

So my guess is, remove those 3 lines and the problem will be gone.